# Could you recommend any open source projects where the source is extensively tested with unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, open-source

Programming is learned by writing programs. But code reading is said to be another good way of learning. I would like to improve my unit-testing skills by reading, examining real-world code. Could you recommend any open source projects where the source is extensively tested with unit tests?

I'm interested in code written in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK C++ Boost libraries - http://boost.org/ - have broadly covered code base, and a policy that every new piece of code must have unit tests with it. Might be worth checking.

Answer (score 4):

The [Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/) project.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it extensively, but [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) does some UnitTest with [CppUnit](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1):

The [Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/) version control system is obsessive about automated testing. Unit testing, feature testing, integration testing, blackbox testing, test doubles testing, testing framework testing, parameterized test suites, platform-specific tests, etc.

This has all sorts of nice consequences for the project, but I must refrain here from undue VCS fanboying.

EDIT: oops, I did not notice you said you were interested in C++. Bazaar is a Python project.

Answer (score 1):

The [trucov](http://code.google.com/p/trucov/) project is an open source tool used to verify unit test coverage.  The tool itself is [extensively](http://code.google.com/p/trucov/wiki/Final_Package_Report) unit tested using [google's test framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).

*Disclaimer*: though I did not write the project myself I did mentor the students who did.