# Looking for *small*, open source, c# project with extensive Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, open-source

(I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282830/looking-for-small-open-source-vbnet-project-with-extensive-unit-testing) question but did not receive much response. It was recommended that I ask the same question with regards to C#. )

I am a VB.NET developer with little C# experience (yes, I know I need to write more in C#), looking for small open source projects that demonstrate high unit testing coverage from which to learn.

I'm looking for ***small*** projects because I don't want to have to wade through a ton of code to get a better understanding of how to apply unit testing in my own situation, in which I write mostly IT business apps used internally by my company.

UPDATE: Original question that got me asking about this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236156/could-you-recommend-any-open-source-projects-where-the-source-is-extensively-te)

Answer (score 3):

My [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) library has variable test coverage - some parts are very thoroughly tested, and others were written before I knew about unit testing.

If you wanted to learn by writing some tests for the uncovered stuff, you'd be very welcome :)

It's a big of a grab-bag of useful bits and pieces - which is handy in some ways, as you can take almost any bit and study it on its own. There's no "overall architecture" to learn.

Comment: some parts are very thoroughly tested, and others were written **before I knew** about unit testing. 

/// Your honesty is admirable.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at FileHelpers (http://www.filehelpers.net/).  I recently had to make an edit to it and found the source code easy to wade through.  It has a large number of tests.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at CarTrackr it has a wide range of .Net technologies that a developer should be familiar with (Unity, MVC framework especially) and has extensive unit testing. The project is simple enough to digest in 1 sitting but complex enough to actually be more than a proof-of-concept. Their codeplex url is at http://www.codeplex.com/CarTrackr

Answer (score 0):

this link is related to Silverlight but the concepts are probably very similar (from a TDD'ish point of view): http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/11/04/test-framework-source/

Answer (score 0):

My [GeoNames .NET WCF Client](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/GeoNames-WCFClient.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[codecampserver.org](http://codecampserver.org)

Comment: There is currently no download there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use a subversion client to check out the source code and run ClickToBuild.bat